# Mixture distribution mean and variance

Tags: self-study, gamma-distribution, mixture-distribution

I'm currently studying zero-modified exponential distributions and working with neither continuous nor discrete distributions, specifically the following general case:

$$ F_{p,m}(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{$x$<0}; \\
1-p+p(1-e^{-x/m}), & \text{$x$>0}
\end{cases} $$

Then what is the mean and variance of rv $x_{p,m}$?
The following is a solution provided in class, which I don't fully understand.

What does the $$(1-p) \cdot 0$$ and $$(1-p) \cdot 0^2$$ mean? And how did we get those?

Also, how did we derive that $$E[X_{p,m}^2] = pm^2 \int^\infty_0 y^2e^{-y}dy$$

[image]

Comment: Plot the cdf to understand the weight at zero.

Comment: I understand why the weight at zero is 0 but I don't get how we got [2,]

Comment: The weight at zero is $1-p$, not zero, and$$\mathbb E[X_{p,m}]=\mathbb E[X_{p,m}\mathbb I_{X_{p,m}=0}]+\mathbb E[X_{p,m}\mathbb I_{X_{p,m}\ne0}]$$

Comment: How did we deduce the weight at zero is 1-p

Comment: Because the weights must sum to unity, according to the probability axioms.

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).